# I'm confused whether I should use URL path parameters or query parameters for filtering on the back-end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Lets say I want to get all car models from a certain car brand. I know I can do it by either using the URL path parameters or the query parameters like this:

```
router.get('/modelsByBrand', modelController.getModelsByBrand);
```

and then make the GET request like this:

```
https://example.com/modelsByBrand?brandId=1
```

and in the controller, get the ID of the brand using this:

```
let brand = req.query.brandId
```

OR

```
router.get('/modelsByBrand/:brandId', modelController.getModelsByBrand);
```

and then make the GET request like this:

```
https://example.com/modelsByBrand/1
```

and in the controller, get the ID of the brand using this:

```
let brand = req.params.brandId
```

But I'm just not sure which one should I use, as both approaches seem almost identical. Are there scenarios where I would need to use one over the other or is it just preference? Can I just use either approach for just about anything?

Comment: Either can work.  My rule of thumb is that I use the path to specify the resource I want and a query parameter to specify a modifier, particularly if there could be many different modifiers.  So, if `brandId` is just one of many modifiers that could be used on the same request, then I"d make it a query parameter so you can have multiple modifiers.  But, if it's the main resource identifier on its own, then I'd put it in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have several parameters to filter and get models then it should look like this:

```
router.get('/models', modelController.getModels);
```

And requests should look like this

```
https://example.com/models // get all models
https://example.com/models?brandId=1 // get all models with brandId = 1
https://example.com/models?name=Model1 // get all models where a name contains "Model1"
https://example.com/models?brandId=1&name=Model1 // get all models with brandId = 1
and a name contains "Model1"
```

And finally to get a model by id

```
router.get('/models/:id', modelController.getModel);
```

And a request

```
https://example.com/models/1 // get a model with id=1
```

I suppose this looks more like RESTful routes.